# Problem by converting a dataframe column into a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, nested-lists

I have a csv file with following structure:

```
Tokens,Tags,Polarities
"['i', 'agree', 'about', 'arafat', '.', 'i', 'mean', ',', 'shit', ',', 'they', 'even', 'gave', 'one', 'to', 'jimmy', 'carter', 'ha', '.', 'it', 'should', 'be', 'called', ""''"", 'the', 'worst', 'president', ""''"", 'prize', '.']","[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]"
"['musicmonday', 'britney', 'spears', '-', 'lucky', 'do', 'you', 'remember', 'this', 'song', '?', 'it', '`', 's', 'awesome', '.', 'i', 'love', 'it', '.']","[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","[-1, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]"
"['wtf', '?', 'hilary', 'swank', 'is', 'coming', 'to', 'my', 'school', 'today', ',', 'just', 'to', 'chill', '.', 'lol', 'wow']","[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","[-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]"
"['my', '3-year-old', 'was', 'amazed', 'yesterday', 'to', 'find', 'that', ""'"", 'real', ""'"", '10', 'pin', 'bowling', 'is', 'nothing', 'like', 'it', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'wii', '...']","[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]","[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1]"
"['God', 'damn', '.', 'That', 'Sony', 'remote', 'for', 'google', 'is', 'fucking', 'hideeeeeous', '!']","[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]","[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1]"
```

I am trying to read the file as follows:

```
twitter_train = pd.read_csv('twitter_train.csv')
```

Then I can see that it has a correct structure:

```
twitter_train.head(3)

Tokens  Tags    Polarities
0   ['i', 'agree', 'about', 'arafat', '.', 'i', 'm...   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -...
1   ['musicmonday', 'britney', 'spears', '-', 'luc...   [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   [-1, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...
2   ['wtf', '?', 'hilary', 'swank', 'is', 'coming'...   [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...
```

I want to convert each column to a list of lists, for example:

```
twitter_train_lists = twitter_train['Tokens'].tolist()
```

But I have incorrect structure that has an extra `\` or `"` with each element in the list and around each list itself:

```
['[\'i\', \'agree\', \'about\', \'arafat\', \'.\', \'i\', \'mean\', \',\', \'shit\', \',\', \'they\', \'even\', \'gave\', \'one\', \'to\', \'jimmy\', \'carter\', \'ha\', \'.\', \'it\', \'should\', \'be\', \'called\', "\'\'", \'the\', \'worst\', \'president\', "\'\'", \'prize\', \'.\']',
 "['musicmonday', 'britney', 'spears', '-', 'lucky', 'do', 'you', 'remember', 'this', 'song', '?', 'it', '`', 's', 'awesome', '.', 'i', 'love', 'it', '.']",
 "['wtf', '?', 'hilary', 'swank', 'is', 'coming', 'to', 'my', 'school', 'today', ',', 'just', 'to', 'chill', '.', 'lol', 'wow']",
 '[\'my\', \'3-year-old\', \'was\', \'amazed\', \'yesterday\', \'to\', \'find\', \'that\', "\'", \'real\', "\'", \'10\', \'pin\', \'bowling\', \'is\', \'nothing\', \'like\', \'it\', \'is\', \'on\', \'the\', \'wii\', \'...\']',
 "['God', 'damn', '.', 'That', 'Sony', 'remote', 'for', 'google', 'is', 'fucking', 'hideeeeeous', '!']"]
```

How I can extract lists properly from this csv file to get the correct structure:

```
[['i', 'agree', 'about', 'arafat', '.', 'i', 'mean', ',', 'shit', ',', 'they', 'even', 'gave', 'one', 'to', 'jimmy', 'carter', 'ha', '.', 'it', 'should', 'be', 'called', "''", 'the', 'worst', 'president', "''", 'prize', '.'],
['musicmonday', 'britney', 'spears', '-', 'lucky', 'do', 'you', 'remember', 'this', 'song', '?', 'it', '`', 's', 'awesome', '.', 'i', 'love', 'it', '.'],
['wtf', '?', 'hilary', 'swank', 'is', 'coming', 'to', 'my', 'school', 'today', ',', 'just', 'to', 'chill', '.', 'lol', 'wow'],
['my', '3-year-old', 'was', 'amazed', 'yesterday', 'to', 'find', 'that', "'", 'real', "'", '10', 'pin', 'bowling', 'is', 'nothing', 'like', 'it', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'wii', '...'],
['God', 'damn', '.', 'That', 'Sony', 'remote', 'for', 'google', 'is', 'fucking', 'hideeeeeous', '!']]
```

You can find the original dataset file here: https://github.com/1tangerine1day/Aspect-Term-Extraction-and-Analysis/tree/master/data

**Update**:
I tried another way but have the same problem:

```
import csv

with open('twitter_train.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

Another incorrect output:

```
print(data[3])

["['wtf', '?', 'hilary', 'swank', 'is', 'coming', 'to', 'my', 'school', 'today', ',', 'just', 'to', 'chill', '.', 'lol', 'wow']", '[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '[-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your info in your csv is actually a string not a list. You need to make them actual lists.

```
twitter_train = pd.read_csv('twitter_train.csv')
twitter_train['Tokens'] = list(twitter_train['Tokens'].str.strip("['").str.rstrip("']").str.split("', '"))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Inspiring by your answer I've just tried with `twitter_train['Tokens'] = list(twitter_train['Tokens'].str.replace("'", "").str.strip("][").str.split(', '))`  which works perfect also!